# Is SoundPool.load() designed to load asynchronously?

Tags: android, multithreading, soundpool

It seems several users have noted that `SoundPool.load()` has regressed with the release of Lollipop ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577132/android-l-soundpool-load-regression), [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81187) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1812)):

The gist of it is that many developers, including myself, have previously called `SoundPool.load()` in the UI-thread, which has worked well in earlier releases of Android, but from Lollipop there seems to be a delay in the order tenths of seconds-seconds when loading small sounds using `SoundPool.load()`.

I have not found any references in the Android documentation that would suggest that `SoundPool.load()` would load the sounds asynchronously, however, the behavior in earlier versions of Android and the existence of a `OnLoadCompleteListener` would imply this (what would otherwise be the point with the listener?)

My question is: Is `SoundPool.load()` supposed to load the sounds asynchronously, and can I design in accordance with this, and expect this to be fixed, or should I start putting this code in an AsyncTask or other background threading mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you any VCS control, you should patch or create a temporal fix and, when the bug is fixed, just revert your changes.

I wouldn't leave it as it is, even if this issue is on google sides, don't risk your user experience, patch it and revert it once it's fixed.

Comment: I realize that this burden should not be passed on to the user. I am interested in knowing the intended usage pattern of SoundPool.load().

Comment: Without code i can't tell for sure if what you're trying to do is ok but, this is a known issue with Lollipop, a bug on google's side so if it was working fine in the past you should keep the same "pattern" once its solved.

Answer (score 3):

**asynchronously** does not necessarily mean **runs on a background thread**.

`SoundPool.load()` clearly runs asynchronously.  The question is whether it is running on the calling thread (typically the main thread), or on a separate thread.

load() calls a native _load() method which equates to android_media_SoundPool_load_FD in [android_media_SoundPool.cpp](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/soundpool/android_media_SoundPool.cpp)

Following the logic onward from there into [SoundPool.cpp](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/soundpool/SoundPool.cpp), [SoundPool.h](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/soundpool/SoundPool.h), and [SoundPoolThread](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/soundpool/SoundPoolThread.cpp), although I'm not well versed in C++ it seems fairly clear that its performing the actual work on a background thread.

It does take a long time to load sounds on some devices (20+ seconds on a little LGE tracfone, but less than 1 second on a more modern Samsung S6), so displaying a progress animation to the user might be appropriate if the sounds cannot be loaded ahead of time.